# scanf() multiple words in C

Tags: c, scanf

I need a simple function that can read multiple words into a string in C, kind of like `Scanner.nextLine()` in Java or `Console.ReadLine()` in C#, but I can't seem to find a simple method anywhere, I tried all sorts of things, but none of them seem to work 100% of the time.

Comment: `fgets()` will grant your wishes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This removes the '\n' character that is included in the string returned by fgets, thus making the function practically equivalent to the functions present in popular managed languages:

```
//gets a line from the specified stream
int getline(char* charArray, int maxLength, FILE* stream) {
    int i;
    if (fgets(charArray, maxLength, stream) == NULL)
        return 1;  //some error occurred
    for (i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        if (charArray[i] == '\n') {
            if (i != 0 && charArray[i - 1] == '\r') //cater for windows line endings
                i--;
            charArray[i] = '\0';
            return 0;  //all's well that ends well
        } else if (charArray[i] == '\0')
            return 0;  //smooth sailing fam
    }
    return 2;  //there was no string terminator
}
```

Comment: Fixed some of the logistics involved, what are the reactions to the fixed version?

Comment: I'd recommend replacing the `for`-loop with `strchr()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

Be aware that fgets reads until reach the size n, or a newline or an EOF.
This is made to avoid buffer overflow, so you need to make sure that your buffer is big enough to store the string.

Comment: Thanks, fgets(charArray, length, stdin) worked beautifully. :)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[50];
    scanf(" %49[^\n]s",string);

    printf("you entered: %s\n",string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this:

```
char str[100];// as length of the total words neded
    fgets(str,100,stdin)

        printf("output: %s",str);

    return 0;
```

Comment: As of C11, `gets()` is no longer a  C standard library function.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets to parse an input string into a char buffer.

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

[Here is the link for a better description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets)

Then use sscanf to dissect this string to however you need it.

```
int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);
```

[Here is the link for a better description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/?kw=sscanf)

Answer (score -3):

Here you go:

```
#include "stdio.h"

//gets a line from the specified stream
int getline(char* charArray, int maxLength, FILE* stream) {
    int i;
    if (fgets(charArray, maxLength, stream) == NULL)
        return 1;  //some error occurred
    for (i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        if (charArray[i] == '\n') {
            if (i != 0 && charArray[i - 1] == '\r') //cater for windows line endings
                i--;
            charArray[i] = '\0';
            return 0;  //all's well that ends well
        } else if (charArray[i] == '\0')
            return 0;  //smooth sailing fam
    }
    return 2;  //there was no string terminator
}

int main() {
    char money[4];
    printf("How much money do you have on you? ");
    getline(money, 4, stdin);
    printf("Oh really? $%d? Good. :)\n", atoi(money));
    char string[4];
    printf("Where is our next lesson?\n");
    getline(string, 4, stdin);
    printf("%s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What on earth were you thinking?